How to install rapidjson-devel in Amazon Linux 2
It seems that recently epel-7 has been removed, and so I can no longer follow instructions from:

How to install epel-release in Red Hat linux 7.8

How would one install rapidjson-devel on Amazon Linux 2 today ?
Steps:
> docker run -it --entrypoint bash public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:7
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
[...]
# yum install rapidjson-devel
Loaded plugins: ovl
No package rapidjson-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do

Since on my side:
# curl -I http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found


Previously it was possible to do it this way:
# yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
# yum -y install rapidjson-devel


Well, Amazon Linux is not RHEL, so it's not that surprising that the installation method is not the same.
Amazon has official documentation that describes the way you install EPEL on AL2:
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y

Then, you can directly install packages from EPEL; don't install individual packages from arbitrary sources!
Generally, you're basing your development work on something that Amazon doesn't support any more, aside from its core packages (and these also only until June 30, 2025 source). This might not be the wisest choice. If this implodes later on, you might be forced to build packages for your legacy distro yourself. That works, it's just a lot of effort compared to upgrading to a newer distro.

In case you don't already have the amazon-linux-extras utility, install the package first:
# yum install amazon-linux-extras


it's interesting you needed to install that; the default amazonlinux:2 container comes with amazon-linux-extras preinstalled
